# How to simulate key press on a background window

Tags: autohotkey

I need to force Outlook which is in the background, to check for new emails every 2 seconds. So I wrote a following script but it doesn't do it. What's wrong? I don't want the script to disturb what I do and give the focus to the Outlook window. The "ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32" is correct, I checked it with "WinActivate, ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32" and it worked.

```
Loop
{
    ControlSend,, {F9}, ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32
    Sleep 2000 ; Wait 2 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in your code. The problem might be in the receiving application. When I test this in Notepad, an <kbd>F5</kbd> (Print time & date) is executed when the Notepad window is open somewhere on my second screen. As soon as I minimize Notepad, it will no longer execute <kbd>F5</kbd>, but it still accepts a string like `A{Enter}B{Enter}C{Enter}` when minimized.

```
!q::
ControlSend,, {F5}A{Enter}B{Enter}C{Enter}, ahk_class Notepad
Return
```

Solution, Try if this works when you keep the window on screen somewhere (no need to have the focus).

I have used Outlook in the past and remember that <kbd>F9</kbd> took some time to execute. Running this every 2 seconds looks like overkill.
If getting your e-mail in time is THAT important that you are willing to "kill" the mail server with refresh requests, I would discuss a solution with your IT support.